# Negative filter with OpenCL

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencl, lodepng

I'm trying to write a program in c++ that inverts RGB values with LodePNG and OpenCL. The kernel seems to build right, but the image doesn't change. There's probably a problem with arguments of queue methods or buffer constructor, but I tried changing them many times and nothing worked.

```
int main()
{
    
    unsigned int start_time = clock();
    vector<unsigned char> png;
    vector<unsigned char> image; //the raw pixels
    unsigned width, height;

    //load and decode
    unsigned error = lodepng::load_file(png, "300x300.png");
    if (!error) error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, png);

    int size = width * height;
    vector<unsigned char> imageCopy = image;
    
    vector<Platform> platforms;
    Platform::get(&platforms);

    _ASSERT(platforms.size() > 0);

    auto platform = platforms.front();
    vector<Device> devices;
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);

    _ASSERT(devices.size() > 0);

    auto device = devices.front();
    Context context(device);

    ifstream sourceFile("kernel.cl");
    string sourceCode(istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length() + 1));
    Program program = Program(context, source);
    program.build(devices);
    if (program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS>(context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>()[0]) != CL_BUILD_SUCCESS) {
        std::string log = program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>()[0]);
        std::cerr << "Build log:\n" << log << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    CommandQueue queue(context, device);

    Buffer imageSize(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int), &size);
    Buffer inputImage(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(imageCopy[0]), imageCopy.data());
    Buffer outputImage(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(image[0]), image.data());

    Kernel kernel(program, "NegativeOCL");
    kernel.setArg(0, inputImage);
    kernel.setArg(1, outputImage);
    kernel.setArg(2, imageSize);

    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, NDRange(size), NDRange(sizeof(int)));

    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(outputImage, CL_TRUE, 0, image.size(), &image[0]);
    queue.finish();

    encodeOneStep("exdee.png", image, width, height);
    unsigned int end_time = clock(); // конечное время
    cout << end_time - start_time; // искомое время
}

/*__kernel void NegativeOCL(__global  unsigned char* inputImage, __global  unsigned char* outputImage, int amount)
{
  int index = get_global_id(0);
  if(index < amount)
  {
    outputImage[index*4] = (255 - inputImage[index*4]); 
    outputImage[index*4 + 1] = (255 - inputImage[index*4 + 1]); 
    outputImage[index*4 + 2] = (255 - inputImage[index*4 + 2]);
  }
}*/
```

Comment: Don't use a buffer for passing the image size (a non-pointer scalar kernel argument) to the kernel. Instead, directly pass a pointer to a `CLint` (which is usually `int`) to `setArg`. Also, as a general recommendation: make sure you are **always** checking OpenCL runtime errors. With the C++ wrappers you can check return values like with the traditional C API, or you can turn these into exceptions using `CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS` if you prefer.

Comment: The use of `NDRange(sizeof(int))` for the work group (local) size suggests a misunderstanding of how work groups work. As you're not using local memory at all in your kernel, I recommend not setting a work group size at all. If global size is not a multiple of local size, this can cause kernel execution to fail altogether. (depending on OpenCL version) And there is no benefit to setting a group size if you're not making use of groups in your kernel. (There is only potential downside if your choice is inefficient.)